# Failed to reset Windows password on Google Cloud VM: "Did not receive password in a reasonable amount of time"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, gcloud, service-accounts

I have created two Google Cloud virtual machines:

- instance1 (Windows Server 2022)
- instance2 (Windows Server 2019)

Through instance1, I need to manage instance2 using the service account XXXXXXXXXXXX-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com. To achieve this, I'm attempting to reset the Windows password of instance2 using the gcloud CLI with the following command:

```
gcloud compute reset-windows-password instance2 --zone=my-zone --project=my-project
```

However, I'm encountering the following error:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.compute.reset-windows-password) Did not receive password in a reasonable amount of time. Please try again.
If this persists, confirm that the clock on your local system is correct.
Current UTC time on your system: [2023-08-21 13:11:24.059083]
```

I've checked the UTC time on both VMs, and they appear to be the same. The curious thing is that if I try the same command on my local PC using the same service account, it succeeds without any issues.

Has anyone else faced a similar issue, or can anyone suggest potential solutions to this problem?

Any insights or assistance in resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be on the right path in resetting the password for instance2, to dig deeper you may need to check other factors like firewalls that may be blocking the communication between the Google Cloud Services and the VM. If possible you can try to do a restart and try again to check if the issue persists. I attached some helpful links for your use case.[1][2]

[1] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/windows/generating-credentials#windows-server-2019

[2] https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/connecting-to-windows